# share on wlan printer connected through ethernet cable

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet

I have a network problem. I am not an expert in networking, though I used to work in tech. support for a while and I know basics in networking and windows/linux utilities for it's administration.

I got a PC, connected to wlan which has several windows machines and apple timecapsule router (I assume it is acting as a gate in this network). There are ethernet cable connecting this PC with an HP officjet pro printer. This printer is working properly with my PC.

Here is the question. Assuming I am using windows 10 on this PC and I cannot use another type of connection with this printer, how can I make this printer discoverable on the main network? I was trying to do port forwarding on the windows machine, but it didn't work for some reason.

I had a rule like this:

```
"netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9100 listenaddress=192.168.1.3 connectport=9100 connectaddress=192.168.0.115"
```

Where 192.168.1.3 is an address of the pc in wlan network and 192.168.1.115 is a printer address in the PC-printer network. This rule I put on the PC. I have ensured previously that from PC I can access web interface on 192.168.1.115 so it is resolving it properly (I assume).

What can I do to solve my problem? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Connect the printer to the network, not to your PC. That will make the printer available on the network to other network connected computers.

Comment: This is not a best option because I don't have ethernet cable long enough. If I obtain it I will have to figure out the was how to throw it from printer to capsule in this small office, this is more trouble then I actually need. Also this capsule has llimited ethernet port number and the are all in usenow.

Comment: Then share the printer from the PC. I'm not sure what you were originally trying to accomplish, but this isn't all that difficult. It doesn't require any netsh or port forwarding mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: Thats my question - I don't know how to share it. Standard windows service are not discovering this printer when I input PC's ip as an address of printer. In a printer properties on PC I set that this printer should be discoverable in a network. I guess since it is physically in other network (consisting of one PC and printer), it is visible there, but not on WLAN.